# What does it mean when spaces blow in Crow's ear cluelessly?

Tags: poetry, ted-hughes

In "Crow Hears Fate Knock On The Door", The lines ending the second part of the song are:

> He walked, he walked
>
> Letting the translucent starry spaces
>
> Blow in his ear cluelessly

I'm trying to understand what did Hughes possibly mean in the last line:

What does it mean to blow "cluelessly"? What could it be that the spaces are clueless about, unaware of?

Moreover, in the preceding lines, Crow is the one who seems clueless:

> "He plucked grass-heads [...] Waiting for first instructions."
>
> "He found a dead mole [...] stared at the goblets, feeling helpless"

So the fact that after those line the "spaces" are depicted as "clueless" seems kind of off this song theme.

Comment: Do you have some reason to believe it means something? As Archibald MacLeish said: "A poem should not mean but be."

Comment: @user14111, yes, I do. When you read "Crow" poems thoroughly (or external sources where Hughes talks about this collection), you realise that Hughes expresses a consistent theme, with each poem elaborating on it from a different perspective. Now, there are, ofcourse, many peculiar, sometimes inexplicable, metaphors and other literary figures, but in the context of a single poem, they make sense, and you can draw the general meaning of them.

Comment: @user14111 more to the point, there isn't really any point to a Q&A site about literature if we can't discuss meaning. Also, you might be interested in https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/917/what-kind-of-research-is-expected-for-questions-here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ted Hughes' Crow cycle is a series of interlinked poems which can be understood, as a whole, to be a folkloric cycle inspired by the Christian tradition. When doing readings, Hughes would introduce this with a spoken word monologue sometimes called *The Quarrel in Heaven* in which God creates the cosmos and Crow becomes God's companion, seeking to understand and improve on his creation.

Further episodes which reflect a biblical narrative include *Apple Tragedy*, which describes Adam and Eve's fall:

> The serpent stared in surprise
>   At this interloper.
>   But God said: "You see this apple?"
>   I squeeze it and look-cider."

And *Crow, Blacker than Ever*, which mirrors the crucifixion:

> Crow nailed them together,
>   Nailing heaven and earth together-
>   So man cried, but with God’s voice.
>   And God bled, but with man’s blood.

Why is this relevant to the quoted work, *Crow Hears Fate Knock on the Door*? If the Crow poems are a meditation on Christianity, then a key aspect of this exploration is contrasting the instinctual religious impulse with the modern desire for rationality, for evidence and experimentation. There are examples all through the cycle, but let's quote one from *Hears Fate*:

> He looked in front of his feet at the little stream
>   Chugging on like an auxiliary motor
>   Fastened to this infinite engine.
>   He imagined the whole engineering
>   Of its assembly, repairs and maintenance —
>   And felt helpless.

Crow is trying to fulfill his role as the explorer of the cosmos through detached observation, but is failing. He is "helpless" to explain both the emotional appeal of the stream and its intricate series of connections to the wider world via rationality.

This is the purpose of the lines:

> He plucked grass-heads and gazed into them
>   Waiting for first instructions.
>   He studied a stone from the stream.
>   He found a dead mole and slowly he took it apart
>   Then stared at the goblets, feeling helpless.

In which Crow is examining the grass, the stone and the dead mole, seeking to understand them by a fixed process. In the first instance this process is tuition, the second observation and the third experimentation - the processes we gradually teach to children as ways of furthering an understanding of the natural world. But to Crow, they are not insightful.

In this context we can understand the couplet

> Letting the translucent starry spaces
>   Blow in his ear cluelessly

To mean that, as he walks, Crow is seeing and thinking ("blow in his ear") about the night sky and its implications and finding himself "clueless" as to what it means. Yet at the same time the sky itself is "clueless": it has no sense of its own purpose.

Indeed, although many a human mind has looked into the starry night and been inspired to wonder on their place in creation, the poem implies that this is a futile quest: there may be no sense in it at all, or at least not one that humanity can understand.

References:
- Violence in the Poetry of Ted Hughes: An Organic Growth, K.T Baby, 1996
- The Laughter of Foxes: A Study of Ted Hughes, Keith Sagar, 2000

Comment: That is a beautiful answer, thank you. You also got me curious when you mentioned *The Quarrel In Heaven*: AFAIK,  there is no published poem with that name, and the only relevant Google [result](http://thetedhughessociety.org/crow/) relate it to a poem that talks about God's nightmare of a Hand and a Voice, which I know of Hughes' recording reading Crow poems. I was wondering if you know otherwise.

Comment: @heyJude thanks, glad you found it useful. Your query about the Quarrel in Heaven is right: I found it in one of the references and, in my haste, mistook the title of a spoken narrative for one of the poems. Apologies: I'll edit this tomorrow to make that clear.